# How to share kv store between vhosts, one for http, another one for https requests

Tags: https, shared-memory, virtualhost, key-value-store, g-wan

Since gwan has not released the documentation of how to use the https features, i am trying to  use a reverse proxy to receive https and pass http to gwan.
My problems are:

1. how to identify the request is coming from the reverse proxy?
2. how to share the kv store between these two vhosts, one for http, one for requests from reverse proxy? I want to share the pointer between these two vhosts ONLY, not across ALL vhosts.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTPS protocol was not publicly release because no protocol compliance tools were found to check the implementation written from scratch.

This lack will probably be "resolved" with the *protocol handlers* which will make it easy to use any available SSL library.

Regarding your project to use an external process, some users reported success with `SSLtunnel`.

1. Reverse-Proxies usually signal their presence with additional HTTP headers (`X-Forwarded-For`, or `X-Real-IP`), but this is also usually configurable and a G-WAN handler will use this information.
2. To share data between virtual hosts (and no other hosts managed by G-WAN), you can use Linux `shared memory`: by using a certain naming convention, you will make sure that those two hosts will find the shared data (read the remark below).

Note that if your 2 virtual hosts are managed by a single instance of G-WAN, then G-WAN scripts will have access to the whole memory range of the process, so, depending on your level of isolation, you might need to run 2 separate processes.